# How to use ReplaceAll iteratively over a list of lists?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, iteration

I want to build a matrix `J` for each of the solutions of an equation.
And each solution is also a set of 3 variables `(x,y,z)`.

In the end, I want to calculate the eigenvalues of `J` for `J` applied to each of the solutions
in the solution set.

I know how to apply the matrix `J` for a given solution,

```
J/.{ x -> a, y -> b, z-> c }
```

if the solution was `(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)`

However, the solution is, for instance,

```
{{x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}, {x -> d, y -> e, z -> f}}
```

So I want to loop over the solution list and apply J for each specific solution.
How can I do that in an automated way?
The simpler, the better... I don't to have to really "code" in Mathematica.

Here is my real problem:

I start from the function

```
F[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := (1 - a + b - (b/3) (c x + d (y + z))) x
```

which generates this set of fixed points (each element of the list FP is a solution)

```
FP = Solve[{x == F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], y == F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], z == F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d]}, {x, y, z}]
```

Then I build the Jacobian matrix:

```
J = FullSimplify[
  {{D[F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], x], D[F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], y], D[F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], z]},
   {D[F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], x], D[F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], y], D[F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], z]},
   {D[F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d], x], D[F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d], y], D[F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d], z]}}
  ]
```

I can calculate the eigenvalues of `J` applied to the first solution like this:

```
Eigenvalues[J/.FP[[1,All]]]
```

But how do I do that iteratively, generating another list?

Thanks

Comment: Are you perhaps aware that you can generate the Jacobian in one blow: `D[{F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d]}, {{x, y, z}}]`?

Comment: No, I wasn't... thanks! I'm completely new to Mathematica...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do that is to use:

```
EV = FullSimplify[Table[Eigenvalues[J /. f], {f, FP}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to iterate manually. First use `ReplaceAll` to substitute *all* eight solutions contained in `FP`, which will give you a list of 8 `J` expressions. Then `Map` the `Eigenvalues` function over the list: this will apply `Eigenvalues` to each element of the list of `J`s in turn, to give you the eight results, one for each solution from `FP`:

```
Eigenvalues /@ (J /. FP)
```

Here are the results:

```
{
 {1 + a - b, 
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c),
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c)},

 {1 + a - b, 
  (c - a c + b c + d + a d - b d)/(c + d), 
  (c + a c - b c + d - a d + b d)/(c + d)},

 {1 + a - b, 
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c),
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c)},
 
 {1 + a - b,
  (c + a c - b c + 2 d - a d + b d)/(c + 2 d), 
  (c + a c - b c + 2 d - a d + b d)/(c + 2 d)},

 {1 + a - b, 
  (c - a c + b c + d + a d - b d)/(c + d), 
  (c + a c - b c + d - a d + b d)/(c + d)}, 

 {1 + a - b,
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c),
  -((-c + a c - b c - a d + b d)/c)}, 

 {1 + a - b, 
  (c - a c + b c + d + a d - b d)/(c + d), 
  (c + a c - b c + d - a d + b d)/(c + d)},

 {1 - a + b, 
  1 - a + b, 
  1 - a + b}
}
```

While we are at it, you do not need the `All` in `FP[[1, All]]`; `FP[[1]]` already means "the first element of FP, whatever is in it". You would use All if you wanted a specific column instead: `FP[[All, 2]]`, which you can read to say:
"take the second element from within all elements of `FP`".

Also, as @J.M. mentioned in comments, your Jacobian can be more simply obtained from:

```
FullSimplify@
 D[
   {F[x, y, z, a, b, c, d], F[y, x, z, a, b, c, d], F[z, x, y, a, b, c, d]}, 
   {{x, y, z}}
 ]
```